# How to specify ppc architecture while building a package with poky?

Tags: package, packaging, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am building a sample package using `bitbake`. Before that, I have created a core image for architecture `ppc` by specifying `MACHINE ?= "qemuppc"` in `conf/local.conf`. The result was

```
~/yocto/poky-daisy-11.0.0/build_qemuppc/tmp/deploy/images/qemuppc/core-image-minimal-qemuppc.ext3
```

Now, for a sample package, I am using following

```
git clone https://github.com/DynamicDevices/meta-example
```

I added this package as a separate layer. The result package was:

```
tmp/deploy/rpm/ppc7400/bbexample-1.0-r0.ppc7400.rpm
```

The expected architecture is `ppc`, but package created for `ppc7400`. How can I specify architecture while building a package?

*Thanks for your time!*

**EDIT**

The target machine where I want to install this package is:

```
#cat /etc/*release*
LSB_VERSION="core-4.1-noarch:core-4.1-powerpc"
DISTRIB_ID=fsl-networking
DISTRIB_RELEASE=1.6
DISTRIB_CODENAME=daisy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 1.6"

#uname -r
3.12.19-rt30-QorIQ-SDK-V1.6+gc29fe1a

#uname -m
ppc
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct - the package contains the architecture of the tune, not the machine name.

Comment: When I install this package on intended machine, I get `warning: package bbexample-1.0-r0.ppc7400 is intended for a ppc7400-unknown-linux platform`. However, I didnt find files in machine after installation, and `rpm -qa` doesnt show this new package name.

Comment: I added some information about target machine in question, Please have a look.

Comment: Don't try to build a package for qemuppc and then put it on an image running a different MACHINE.  Your target is using a qoriq machine from meta-fsl-ppc, so pick the appropriate machine from there.